# Postman returning error message after query for a rest endpoint

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

Getting error messages and I have troubleshooted all I could but it won't work. I keep getting an error message, what could be wrong?

Here is the controller:

```
package com.Controller;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.Model.*;
import com.Service.UserAccountService;


@RestController
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    UserAccountService userService;

    @RequestMapping(path = "/users/")
    public List<UserAccount> getUsers()
    {
        return userService.getUsers();
    }
}
```

This is the Service interface and ServiceImpl:

```
package com.Service;

import java.util.List;

import com.Exceptions.UserNotFoundException;
import com.Model.UserAccount;


public interface UserAccountService {

    UserAccount save(UserAccount user) throws Exception;

    List<UserAccount> getUsers();

    UserAccount update(UserAccount user, int id) throws Exception;

    //UserAccount delete(UserAccount user) throws Exception;

    UserAccount userAccountByKey(int id) throws UserNotFoundException;
   }
```

This is the code for the service implementation:

```
package com.ServiceImpl;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.Exceptions.UserNotFoundException;
import com.Model.UserAccount;
import com.Repository.UserRepo;
import com.Service.UserAccountService;

@Service
public class UserAccountServiceImplementation implements UserAccountService {

@Autowired  
private UserRepo repo;


@Override
public List<UserAccount> getUsers() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    List<UserAccount> users = new ArrayList<>();
    repo.findAll().forEach(users::add);
    return users;
}
```

This is the code for the model:

```
package com.Model;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
//import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

@Entity
public class UserAccount {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    @NotNull
    private String userName;
    private String email;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date dateCreated;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "userAccount", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set <Transaction> transactions = new HashSet<>();


    public UserAccount(int id) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
    }


    public UserAccount(String userName, String email, Date dateCreated) {
        super();
        this.userName = userName;
        this.email = email;
        this.dateCreated = dateCreated;
    }


    public UserAccount(int id, String userName, String email, Date dateCreated) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.userName = userName;
        this.email = email;
        this.dateCreated = dateCreated;
    }


    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }
    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
    public Date getDateCreated() {
        return dateCreated;
    }
    public void setDateCreated(Date dateCreated) {
        this.dateCreated = dateCreated;
    }
    public Set<Transaction> getTransactions() {
        return transactions;
    }
    public void setTransactions(Set<Transaction> transactions) {
        this.transactions = transactions;
    }


    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(id,userName,email,dateCreated);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        UserAccount other = (UserAccount) obj;
        if (!Objects.equals(this.id, other.id)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder ("UserAccount{");
        sb.append("id=").append(id);
        sb.append(",username='").append(userName).append('\'');
        sb.append(",email='").append(email).append('\'');
        sb.append(",date='").append(dateCreated).append('\'');
        sb.append('}');
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

This is my application.properties data:

```
  spring.h2.console.enabled=true
  spring.datasource.platform=h2
  spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
  spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:mojec
  spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
  spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
  spring.datasource.data=classpath:data.sql
```

It is giving me worries.

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Please provide the error message that you are getting.

Comment: @JRK  The error message : "error": "Not Found",

Comment: @HarryManoharan  The error message is : "error": "Not Found",

Answer (score 0):

Your request mapping need to specify the httpmethod like this :

`@RequestMapping(value= "/users",  method=RequestMethod.GET)`

Comment: I have added the method.RequestMethod.GET but it still throw "error": "Not Found", on postman

Comment: `RequestMapping` uses `RequestMethod.GET` by default.

Answer (score 0):

The `RestController` is never configured by Spring as it cannot be detected by Spring Boot's component scan (in fact, none of your other bean classes are scanned as well). The issue here is that you have a package structure like this:

```
com.Wallet
  - WalletApplication.java
com.Controller
  - UserController.java
com.Service
  - UserAccountServiceImpl.java
```

Now since, the `mainClass` is in package `com.Wallet` it would scan for bean definitions inside that package (or a sub-package in `com.Wallet`). So:

- either you move all the packages such as `com.Controller`, `com.ServiceImpl` etc. **inside** `com.Wallet`, ie -

```
com.Wallet
   |
   |- WalletApplication.java
   |
   |- Controller
   |  |
   |  |- UserController.java
   | 
   |- Service
      |
      |- UserAccountServiceImpl.java
```

- or, use `@ComponentScan` in your main class -

```
@EnableJpaRepositories
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.Controller", "com.ServiceImpl", .. })
public class WalletApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(WalletApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

I suggest the first option, as it lends your application a cleaner package structure.

Comment: Thanks much it worked when I changed the name of the packages and added the base package but I am getting an empty result for the rest GET method . Just two array brackets like this [] . Do I need to add a Jar file ?

Comment: Do you have proper data in the database, that matches the criteria of your `GET` endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the package structure at first. for example if the main class is in com.example, others classes will follow com.example.controller, com.example.model etc. @ComponentScan will scan the base packages after com.example..

Answer (score -2):

Do not directly access the interface from the controller. Access it through the service layer.

you should create an instance of your service class not interface class.

change

```
     @Autowired
     UserAccountService userService;
```

to

```
    @Autowired
    UserAccountServiceImplementation userService;
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200763/discussion-on-answer-by-harry-manoharan-postman-returning-error-message-after-qu).